# Odd fstream issue

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I've got an odd error with all my programs I've written no longer reading the files they're referenced to even if they're in the same directory. I tried old programs that I've written and tested and haven't touched for months yet now they return my ERROR message. I even wrote a simple program to test it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    fstream openFile;
    int num, cnt=0;

    openFile.open("data.dat");

    if (!openFile) {
        cout << "ERROR opening file" << endl;
    } else {
       cout << "I'm open!" << endl;
       while(openFile >> num)
        cout << num << endl;
        cnt++;
    }

    cout << cnt << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return(0);
}
```

Information on file:

```
1
2
5
66
9
4
2
```

This returns the ERROR message and cnt at 0. The file is located in the exact same directory as the executable. 
What exactly could be causing this? Is there an issue with my program?

Comment: while or any loop just take 1st statement after it try to add body of while loop. `while(openFile >> num){
        cout << num << endl;
        cnt++;}`

Comment: can you little explain what you want? It's just looking many errors in your code and what is this statement? `cout << num << endl;`

Comment: @AsifMushtaq First, thank you for pointing out the while loop's body issue. I overlooked that. But the problem is it doesn't even attempt to read the file. That's why I have the if statement there saying that if it can't read the file print the ERROR message. It doesn't even recognize the file's existence in the same directory at all and all my programs which previously worked with similar conditions have the same issue even though I haven't edited or recompiled them.

Comment: @AsifMushtaq that last statement prints the amount of lines on the file after the while loop has gone through all the lines of the file. What other issues do you see?

Comment: It doesn't happen magically. You changed something. Figure out what it was.

Comment: @Asif: What's confusing about `cout << num << endl`?

Comment: _"even if they're in the same directory"_ The same directory as what?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that's the issue, I have no idea what was changed. I didn't personally change anything recently (though I did update Windows so that may have something to do with it?). I posted this question to see if anyone had any idea what could have possibly been changed and how to reverse it. And the executable and data.dat are in the same directory.

Comment: @Asa: Hint: where did you read that the location of the executable has anything to do with it? :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I appreciate the whole "Please just put relevant info in the question" thing you got going on here and I'll check that but honestly if you're not gong to help me with this I really don't see a reason to continue going back and forth lol. I just wanted to try to avoid answers like "Check that the file in the correct place" is all :\

Comment: This is probably nothing to do with your code and everything to do with your build process. Tell use what program you're using, at least. (Most likely the program's current working directory isn't what you expect it to be.)

Comment: @celticminstrel I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 and I'll check that

Comment: @Asa: Um all I did was give you a helpful hint for free. Guess I won't do that again...... In the meantime, think about the answer to my question and you'll be three steps closer to the answer for yours. Yes, you have to apply _thought_. Sucks, doesn't it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Know what? I'm dumb for this one because the answer was extremely obvious. Wasn't trying to disrespect, it just seemed like you were being sarcastic is all and I really don't have time for that. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AsaGayle: I obviously wasn't